# Hammer JS swipe calendar dates

Tags: jquery-plugins, hammer.js

I have hammer js and the jquery-hammer plugin that handles a very simple swipe action.

What should happen is that when I swipe left I have a calendar with a date that goes back with one day and when I swipe right it should go forward with one day. At the moment when I swipe it jumps multiple days depending on the direction I swipe and the time the swipe took (I'm guessing).

When I change this function to simple click events on a left and right container, the dates advance only one day per click as expected.

```
event.gesture.preventDefault();
```

gives a "not function error"

**How can I get the swipe to only call this function once for every swipe?**

```
module.exports = View.extend({
    template: 'bookings/templates/components/body',
    className:'bookings-lists',
    deviceType: App.browser.device.deviceType,
    events: {
        'swipe' : 'swipeMe'
    },
    swipeMe: function(e){
        var that = this;
        container.hammer().on('swipeleft', function(event) {
            event.gesture.preventDefault();
            that.model.pushDateForward();
        }).on('swiperight', function(event) {
            event.gesture.preventDefault();
            that.model.pushDateBackward();
        });
    } });
```

Comment: I managed to change the drag_lock_min_distance to 50 so now you have to swipe for 50px before it changes the date and in doing so the date only changes once. Not ideal because on mobiles that is a large swipe. Any other suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

My comment above is totally wrong. Checking what direction the swipe is rather than just relying on built in "swipeleft" or "swiperight" works. No more multiple date changes.

```
swipeMe: function(e){

        if(e.gesture.direction === 4)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.model.pushDateBackward();
        }
        else if(e.gesture.direction === 2)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.model.pushDateForward();
        }
    },
```